# How to set axis length in R

Tags: r, axis

I'm new using R, so I want to know if there is a way to set the axis length to a fixed value like 5 cm.

```
par(pty="s")
a1=c(22.02, 23.83,  26.67,  25.38,  25.49,  23.50,  25.90,  24.89)
a2=c(21.49, 22.67,  24.62,  24.18,  22.78,  22.56,  24.46,  23.79)
a3=c(20.33, 21.67,  24.67,  22.45,  22.29,  21.95,  20.49,  21.81)
boxplot(a1,a2,a3, las=1)
```

I'm getting

[image]

Is ther a way to set the axis length to a fixed value??

EDIT 1

I want something like this (sorry for the quality)

[image]

Comment: Use par for the outer margins and subtracting the first and third from the setting in the graphics device. Also clarify for yourself whether you want the length between 21 and 22 to be an inch or you want "the axis length to a fixed value" to be 5 inches. To my mind those are different requests.

Comment: I want that the square containing the boxplot has 5x5 cm

Comment: Seems that would just involve using the height specification for the graphics device and the "mai" parameter to `par`.

Comment: I recommend to render the plot using svg or pdf and then resizing it in a suitable vectorized software eg inkscape, gimp, ps,... or try to play with something like this `jpeg("test.jpg", width = 5, height = 5, units = "cm", res=75);par(mar=c(0,0,0,0));plot(1:10);dev.off()`

Answer (score 1):

First you may set up graphics window dimensions with `win.graph`. E.g. default

```
win.graph(7,7)
```

gives you 7 inch x 7 inch graphics window.

Then you set up outer margins (in inches also):

```
par(mai=c(2,2,2,2))
```

Numbers inside `c()` are bottom, left, top and right margin widths (in inches).

So

```
win.graph(7,7)
par(mar=c(2,2,2,2))
```

leaves 5 inch x 5 inch square for the plot. You just need to convert inches to cm and choose arguments for `win.graph` to cover your axis labels.